# Angular applying flex layout to component that is injected using "router-outlet"

Tags: angular, flexbox

I have a problem with applying flex layout to a component that is injected into place using the "router-outlet" method.

```
  <app-eis-card-body >
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
  </app-eis-card-body>
```

Using my flex layout the parent div "app-eis-card-body" has the correct height.
Elsewhere in the app layout where I not using 'router-outlet' I have noticed that for flex to work I have to apply flex layout styles to the custom component tag if the flex is to work correctly

How can I set the flex style for my injected component?  Also I'm wondering if the 'router-outlet' tag is messing up the flex layout.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If I have not misunderstood, it may be worth using `:host` pseudo-class selector:
https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host